# Calc 3 double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute the double integral of $f(x,y)=3\sin(5x)$ over the domain $D$ bounded by $x=0, x=\frac{\pi}{10}, y=0, y=\cos(5x)$.

I am having trouble solving this double integral. I know that I must go from $0$ to $\cos(5x)$ for $dy$ and $0$ to $\frac\pi{10}$ for $dx$. Maybe I am just making a simple integration error, but I am not sure. If anyone could help me with steps and/or a solution I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have\begin{align}
\iint_D f(x,y) \, dy dx = \int_0^{\pi/10} \int_0^{\cos 5x} 3 \sin 5x \, dy dx = 3\int_0^{\pi/10}  \sin 5x  \cos 5x \,  dx
\end{align}
Now we have $3 \int_0^{\pi/10} \sin 5x \cos 5x \, dx$ as our single-variable integral. Can you try to integrate from here? Try using substitution rule with $u=\sin 5x$.

According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2aintegrate+from+0+to+pi%2F10+sin+5x+cos+5x), your answer should be $\displaystyle \frac{3}{10}$, if your work is done correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was very helpful.